# Завершение активности фрагмента

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

Здравствуйте, объясню по простому...у меня есть приложение, слева выдвигается менюшка. В списке меню есть пункт "ВОЙТИ", при нажатии на него я запускаю фрагмент с авторизацией. Вот собственно в чём вопрос, а как удалить фрагмент после того как например пользователь залогинился?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартный метод вызываете, когда фрагмент больше не нужен.

```
objectFragment.dismiss();
```